# No restore button in maximised window

Tags: win32gui, mdichild

When I maximise one of my mdi client windows. I am then stuck with it maximised, I need to be able to restore it to view the other windows.

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;

wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = CWindowHandler::MsgRouter;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = childClassName;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

hChild = CreateMDIWindow(childClassName, "Segments", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, m_winRect.left, m_winRect.top, m_winRect.right - m_winRect.left, m_winRect.bottom - m_winRect.top, CWindowHandler::GetInstance()->GetMDIClient(), m_hInstance, (LPARAM)this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed this by calling return DefMDIChildProc(m_Hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); in the case WM_SIZE: of the wndprocs of the child window. god knows why but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to have to add the style [MDIS_ALLCHILDSTYLES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to get the window styles you want.  From MSDN...

> The style of the MDI child window. **If the MDI client window is created
>   with the MDIS_ALLCHILDSTYLES window style, this parameter can be any
>   combination of the window styles listed in the Window Styles page**.
>   Otherwise, this parameter is limited to one or more of the following
>   values.

Comment: thanks, but I just tried that and get the same result. I tried MDIS_ALLCHILDSTYLES | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW in CreateMDIWindow(). What's also weird is I also tried | WS_MAXIMIZE to make it initially maximised, and not only did it make it initially maximised but it also added the missing restore and minimise buttons, however pressing them did nothing.